# View model data lost after posting to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my view model:

```
public class AgencyViewModel
{
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase SpreadsheetFile { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my two controller methods:

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var viewModel = new AgencyViewModel
    {
        Vendors = _vendorsRepository.Vendors.OrderBy(v => v.Name)
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(AgencyViewModel viewModel)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

And my view:

```
@model MyModels.AgencyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Agencies", FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VendorId,
        new SelectList(Model.Vendors, "VendorID", "Name"),
        "- Select a Vendor -")

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SpreadsheetFile, new { type = "file" })

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </p>
}
```

When I navigate to `Upload`, the `Vendors` are loaded correctly. But when I submit my form, my view model only contains `VendorId` and `SpreadsheetFile`, and `Vendors` is `null`.

I need to do some work with the `Vendors` collection after I submit the form, and I don't want to load the all the data twice.

How can I keep the data in my view model?

Comment: passing your business logic (vendor) to view directly is not a good practice.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi - what should I do instead?

Comment: _I don't want to load the all the data twice._ what does this mean ?

Comment: Agree with emre, the logic to work with Vendors should place inside BLL layer, get from DB again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your ViewData again, you can use an ActionFilter if you want to keep it DRY, another choice would be overriding the controllers OnActionExecuted method and loading your data there.

If you are doing good use of the MVC pattern you should only need to load the viewdata when the validation fails, since in that case you would load the same view again.

Answer (score 1):

After submitted a form we can get the values of HTML controls using their **name** attribute only and your dropdownlist in getting render in html like this:

```
<select name="VendorId" id="VendorId"><option value="1">XYZ</option>
```

That is why you are able to get the value of VendorId but not the Model.Vendors because no control is being created with the name Vendors.

You can store this list in session or can call the database procedure once again to get the list after your form submission.